How can I center a svg text element vertically?
In the code below, I was able to determine the yOffset value by trial and error.
I would prefer to calculate the value instead so the text will be vertically centered.
How can I do that?
The documentation for the SVG Text element says:

The y coordinate of the starting point of the text baseline, or the y
coordinate of each individual glyph if a list of values is provided.
Value type: List of (|) ; Default value: 0;
Animatable: yes

So, I need to be able to determine what the baseline is to solve this problem generally. How can I do that?


function measureSVGText(text, fontSize, fontFamily) {
  // Create an offscreen SVG element
  const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  
  svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  svg.setAttribute("width", "0");
  svg.setAttribute("height", "0");
  svg.style.position = "absolute";
  svg.style.top = "-9999px";
  svg.style.left = "-9999px";

  // Create a text element
  const textElement = document.createElementNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "text"
  );
  
  textElement.setAttribute("x", "0");
  textElement.setAttribute("y", "0");
  textElement.style.fontSize = fontSize;
  textElement.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
  textElement.textContent = text;

  // Append the text element to the SVG
  svg.appendChild(textElement);
  document.body.appendChild(svg);

  // Get the bounding box of the text element
  const bbox = textElement.getBBox();
  const roundedBBox = svg.createSVGRect();

  roundedBBox.width = Math.ceil(bbox.width);
  roundedBBox.height = Math.ceil(bbox.height);

  // Remove the SVG element from the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(svg);

  return roundedBBox;
}

function createSVGLabel(text) {
  const padding = 4;
  const fontSize = 10;
  const fontFamily = "Roboto";
  const bbox = measureSVGText(text, `${fontSize}px`, fontFamily);

  const svgWidth = bbox.width + padding * 2;
  const svgHeight = bbox.height + padding * 2;
  const yOffset = 13;
  
  const svg =
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
    `<svg width="${svgWidth}" height="${svgHeight}" viewBox="0 0 ${svgWidth} ${svgHeight}" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` +
    `<rect width="${svgWidth}" height="${svgHeight}" rx="10" ry="10" style="fill:white" />` +
    `<text x="4" y="${yOffset}" font-family="${fontFamily}" font-size="${fontSize}" fill="black">${text}</text>` +
    "</svg>";

  return svg;
}

const label = createSVGLabel("00000");

const parser = new DOMParser();
const labelDocument = parser.parseFromString(label, "image/svg+xml");
const labelNode = labelDocument.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
const container = document.getElementById("container");

container.appendChild(labelNode);
<div id="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black;">
</div>




Just set dominant-baseline="central"


function measureSVGText(text, fontSize, fontFamily) {
  // Create an offscreen SVG element
  const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  
  svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  svg.setAttribute("width", "0");
  svg.setAttribute("height", "0");
  svg.style.position = "absolute";
  svg.style.top = "-9999px";
  svg.style.left = "-9999px";

  // Create a text element
  const textElement = document.createElementNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "text"
  );
  
  textElement.setAttribute("x", "0");
  textElement.setAttribute("y", "0");
  textElement.style.fontSize = fontSize;
  textElement.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
  textElement.textContent = text;

  // Append the text element to the SVG
  svg.appendChild(textElement);
  document.body.appendChild(svg);

  // Get the bounding box of the text element
  const bbox = textElement.getBBox();
  const roundedBBox = svg.createSVGRect();

  roundedBBox.width = Math.ceil(bbox.width);
  roundedBBox.height = Math.ceil(bbox.height);

  // Remove the SVG element from the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(svg);

  return roundedBBox;
}

function createSVGLabel(text) {
  const padding = 4;
  const fontSize = 10;
  const fontFamily = "Roboto";
  const bbox = measureSVGText(text, `${fontSize}px`, fontFamily);

  const svgWidth = bbox.width + padding * 2;
  const svgHeight = bbox.height + padding * 2;
  
  const svg =
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
    `<svg width="${svgWidth}" height="${svgHeight}" viewBox="0 0 ${svgWidth} ${svgHeight}" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` +
    `<rect width="${svgWidth}" height="${svgHeight}" rx="10" ry="10" style="fill:white" />` +
    `<text x="4" y="${svgHeight / 2}" font-family="${fontFamily}" font-size="${fontSize}" fill="black" dominant-baseline="central">${text}</text>` +
    "</svg>";

  return svg;
}

const label = createSVGLabel("00000");

const parser = new DOMParser();
const labelDocument = parser.parseFromString(label, "image/svg+xml");
const labelNode = labelDocument.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
const container = document.getElementById("container");

container.appendChild(labelNode);
<div id="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black;">
</div>




There is no need for BBox voodoo magic to center text in SVG

add a hidden <path id="guide">
position text with <textPath href="#guide">
Change font-size by changing the viewBox 80 20 and path m0 10h80 values




<svg viewbox="0 0 80 20" style="background:red">
  <rect rx="5%" fill="beige" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  <path id="guide" d="m0 10h80" stroke="red"/>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#guide" startoffset="50%" 
              text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central"
              font-family="Roboto">00000</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>



Note
You could do <text x=50% y=50% text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" ...
But due to the percentages that will not work in a larger SVG
